# Calling the instance value In the WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, woocommerce

So far, I have asked a few questions, but no one has answered, but I will ask again, I hope someone will answer, First, let me say that I am learning programming, so don't be offended if my question is a beginner.

I want to add the product comparison feature to WooCommerce, because there are several plugins on the internet for every possibility, if I have to install one plugin for every possibility, it will slow down the site speed and cause other problems. For this reason, I download the desired plugin and extract the option I want from it and implement it in my template.

I use the [WCBoost – Products Compare](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wcboost-products-compare/) plugin to compare products, I moved some of the functions to my template as well as those connected to the WooCommerce hook, Inside the functions, some functions were created for WooCommerce and others were created by the plugin. I did not touch the WooCommerce functions, but I also added some plugin functions to my template for proper functionality. But some other functions are defined in such a way that due to my lack of knowledge I don't know how to transfer them, I will put 2 examples here, I hope you will help me in learning programming :

The following function adds a compare button to the store page and I added it to my template :

```
    function loop_add_to_compare_button() {
        global $product;
        $args = get_button_template_args();
        $args['class'] .= ' wcboost-products-compare-button--loop';
        echo apply_filters(
            'wcboost_products_compare_loop_add_to_compare_link',
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" data-product_id="%d" class="%s" aria-label="%s" role="button">
                    %s
                    <span class="wcboost-products-compare-button__text">%s</span>
                </a>',
                esc_url( isset( $args['url'] ) ? $args['url'] : add_query_arg( [ 'add-to-compare' => $product->get_id() ] ) ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['product_id'] ) ? $args['product_id'] : $product->get_id() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'wcboost-products-compare-button wcboost-products-compare-button--loop button' ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['aria-label'] ) ? $args['aria-label'] : sprintf( __( 'Compare %s', 'wcboost-products-compare' ), '&ldquo;' . $product->get_title() . '&rdquo;' ) ),
                empty( $args['icon'] ) ? '' : '<span class="wcboost-products-compare-button__icon">' . $args['icon'] . '</span>',
                esc_html( isset( $args['label'] ) ? $args['label'] : __( 'Compare', 'wcboost-products-compare' ) )
            ),
            $args
        );
    } add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'loop_add_to_compare_button', 15 );
```

Inside this function is a function written by the plugin, and I had to add it to my template for it to function properly : `$args = get_button_template_args();`

```
    function get_button_template_args( $product = false ) {
        $product = $product ? $product : $GLOBALS['product'];
        $list    = Plugin::instance()->list;
        $args = [
            'product_id' => $product->get_id(),
            'class'      => [ 'wcboost-products-compare-button' ],
            'label'      => get_button_text( 'add' ),
            'aria-label' => sprintf( __( 'Compare %s', 'wcboost-products-compare' ), '&ldquo;' . $product->get_title() . '&rdquo;' ),
            'url'        => get_add_url( $product ),
        ];
        if ( apply_filters( 'wcboost_products_compare_button_uses_ajax', true ) ) {
            $args['class'][] = 'wcboost-products-compare-button--ajax';
        }
        if ( $list && $list->has_item( $product ) ) {
            $args['class'][] = 'added';
            $args['icon']    = get_compare_icon( true );
            switch ( get_option( 'wcboost_products_compare_exists_item_button_behaviour', 'remove' ) ) {
                case 'hide':
                    $args['class'][] = 'hidden';
                    break;
                case 'remove':
                    $args['url']        = get_remove_url( $product );
                    $args['aria-label'] = sprintf( __( 'Remove %s from the compare list', 'wcboost-products-compare' ), '&ldquo;' . $product->get_title() . '&rdquo;' );
                    $args['label']      = get_button_text( 'remove' );
                    break;
                case 'view':
                    $args['url']        = wc_get_page_permalink( 'compare' );
                    $args['aria-label'] = __( 'Open the compare list', 'wcboost-products-compare' );
                    $args['label']      = get_button_text( 'view' );
                    break;
                case 'popup':
                    $args['url']        = wc_get_page_permalink( 'compare' );
                    $args['aria-label'] = __( 'Open the compare list', 'wcboost-products-compare' );
                    $args['label']      = get_button_text( 'view' );
                    $args['class'][]    = 'wcboost-products-compare-button--popup';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $args['icon']  = get_compare_icon( false );
        }
        $args = apply_filters( 'wcboost_products_compare_button_template_args', $args, $product );
        if ( in_array( 'button', $args['class'] ) ) {
            $args['class'][] = get_element_class_name( 'button' );
        }
        $args['class'] = implode( ' ', (array) $args['class'] );
        return $args;
    }
```

But in this function, a function is defined by the plugin that I don't know how to call it : `$list = Plugin::instance()->list;`.

I think you mean to get all the properties of the plugin class, But I don't know how to transfer it to my heart.

plugin.php

```
<?php
namespace WCBoost\ProductsCompare;

/**
 * Plugin main class
 */
final class Plugin {

    /**
     * Plugin version.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $version = '1.0.1';

    /**
     * The product list to compare
     *
     * @var Compare_List
     */
    public $list;

    /**
     * The single instance of the class.
     *
     * @var \WCBoost\ProductsCompare\Plugin
     */
    protected static $_instance = null;

    /**
     * Main instance. Ensures only one instance of the plugin class is loaded or can be loaded.
     *
     * @static
     * @return \WCBoost\ProductsCompare\Plugin
     */
    public static function instance() {
        if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Cloning is forbidden.
     */
    public function __clone() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Foul!', 'wcboost-products-compare' ), '1.0.0' );
    }

    /**
     * Unserializing instances of this class is forbidden.
     */
    public function __wakeup() {
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'Foul!', 'wcboost-products-compare' ), '1.0.0' );
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->includes();
        $this->init();
    }

    /**
     * Plugin URL getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function plugin_url( $path = '/' ) {
        return untrailingslashit( plugins_url( $path, dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );

    }

    /**
     * Plugin path getter.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function plugin_path() {
        return untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );
    }

    /**
     * Plugin base name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function plugin_basename() {
        return dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 2 ) . '/wcboost-products-compare.php';
    }

    /**
     * Load files
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function includes() {
        include_once 'admin/settings.php';
        include_once 'helper.php';
        include_once 'form-handler.php';
        include_once 'ajax-handler.php';
        include_once 'compare-list.php';
        include_once 'frontend.php';
        include_once 'shortcodes.php';
        include_once 'compatibility.php';
        include_once 'customizer.php';
        include_once 'widgets/products-compare.php';
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the plugin
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function init() {
        $this->init_hooks();

        Install::init();
        Form_Handler::init();
        Ajax_Handler::init();
        Shortcodes::init();

        Frontend::instance();
    }

    /**
     * Core hooks to run the plugin
     */
    protected function init_hooks() {
        add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'load_translation' ] );
        add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'initialize_list' ] );

        add_action( 'widgets_init', [ $this, 'register_widgets' ] );

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_compare_page_id', [ $this, 'compare_page_id' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Load textdomain.
     */
    public function load_translation() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'wcboost-products-compare', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 2 ) . '/languages/' );
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the list of compare products
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize_list() {
        $this->list = new Compare_List();
    }

    /**
     * Empty product list.
     * Initialize a new list of compare products.
     *
     * @param  bool $reset_db
     * @return void
     */
    public function empty_list( $reset_db = false ) {
        $this->list->empty( $reset_db );

        if ( $reset_db ) {
            $this->initialize_list();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register widgets
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register_widgets() {
        register_widget( '\WCBoost\ProductsCompare\Widget\Products_Compare_Widget' );
    }

    /**
     * Get the compare page id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function compare_page_id() {
        $page_id = get_option( 'wcboost_products_compare_page_id' );
        $page_id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $page_id, 'page', false, null );

        return $page_id;
    }
}
```

compare-list.php

```
<?php
namespace WCBoost\ProductsCompare;

/**
 * Compare products list
 */
class Compare_List {

    const SESSION_KEY = 'wcboost_products_compare_list';

    /**
     * The list id
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * The list of product ids
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $items = [];

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct( $product_ids = [] ) {
        if ( ! empty( $product_ids ) ) {
            $this->load_products_manually( $product_ids );
        } else {
            $this->id = wc_rand_hash();
            $this->load_products_from_session();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the list id
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_id() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get product list from WC()->session
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function load_products_from_session() {
        if ( ! WC()->session ) {
            return;
        }

        $data = WC()->session->get( self::SESSION_KEY, [ 'id' => '', 'items' => [] ] );

        foreach ( $data['items'] as $product_id ) {
            $key = Helper::generate_item_key( $product_id );
            $this->items[ $key ] = $product_id;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $data['id'] ) ) {
            $this->id = $data['id'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the list data manually.
     * Manully add products to the list.
     *
     * @param  array $product_ids
     * @return void
     */
    protected function load_products_manually( $product_ids ) {
        foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

            if ( ! $product ) {
                continue;
            }

            $key = Helper::generate_item_key( $product_id );
            $this->items[ $key ] = $product_id;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the list items.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_items() {
        return $this->items;
    }

    /**
     * Count the number of items
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count_items() {
        return count( $this->items );
    }

    /**
     * Add a new product to the list and update the session
     *
     * @param  int | WC_Product $product
     * @return int | bool TRUE if successful, FALSE otherwise
     */
    public function add_item( $product ) {
        $product_id = is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product;
        $key        = Helper::generate_item_key( $product_id );

        if ( ! $this->has_item( $product ) ) {
            $this->items[ $key ] = $product_id;

            // Update the session.
            $this->update();

            do_action( 'wcboost_products_compare_product_added', $product_id );

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a product from the list.
     *
     * @param string $key
     *
     * @return int|bool The removed product ID if successful, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function remove_item( $key ) {
        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $this->items ) ) {
            $product_id = $this->items[ $key ];
            unset( $this->items[ $key ] );

            $this->update();

            do_action( 'wcboost_products_compare_product_removed' );

            return $product_id;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Empty the list.
     * Also reset the ID to create a new list.
     *
     * @param  bool $reset_db Reset data in the database
     * @return void
     */
    public function empty( $reset_db = false ) {
        $this->items = [];

        if ( $reset_db ) {
            $this->id = '';
            $this->delete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if a product exist in the list
     *
     * @param  int | \WC_Product $product
     * @return bool
     */
    public function has_item( $product ) {
        $product_id = is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product;

        return in_array( $product_id, $this->items );
    }

    /**
     * Check if the list is empty
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is_empty() {
        return $this->count_items() ? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * Update the session.
     * Just update the product ids to the session.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function update() {
        // Initialize the customer session if it is not already initialized.
        if ( WC()->session && ! WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC()->session->set_customer_session_cookie( true );
        }

        if ( $this->id ) {
            WC()->session->set( self::SESSION_KEY, [
                'id'    => $this->id,
                'items' => array_values( $this->items ),
            ] );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete the list data from the database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function delete() {
        // Initialize the customer session if it is not already initialized.
        if ( WC()->session && WC()->session->has_session() ) {
            WC()->session->set( self::SESSION_KEY, null );
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I'm learning programming, forgive me if my question is a beginner, I hope my friends will help.

thanks to everyone

Comment: Did you try adding the namespace to the plugin’s class: `WCBoost\ProductsCompare\Plugin::instance()->list()`

Comment: Btw: copying code from a plugin and then using it can be helpful when trying to understand their code and learning to code, but it is  not a thing you should normally be doing. The plugin might contain a bug that the plugin maker’s might solve in the future and release an updated version of their plugin to solve this bug. If you copy/paste their code, your copied version will not get updated…